# Amplitude amplification in Grover algorithm

Tags: quantum-gate, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

In "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information", they talk about Grover search. One part of the Grover search is Amplitude amplification:
[image]

But i think the red line is not true. Because i do a matrix multiplication, and they did not give the same matrix.
[image]
[image]

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. You're just forgetting that there's an equivalence up to global phases. Multiply one answer by $-1$ and you have the other. Hence, they are the same up to a global phase.

Comment: i think you are right. But i dont totally understand it. If the matrix of the first Oracle is multiple by -1, then the answer would be wrong?

Comment: No, it just means that your overall state vector would be multiplied by $-1$, which has no observable difference.

Comment: In Grover's algorithm, the first Oracle is Phase Inversion right? If the Oracle is multiple by -1, it's mean we are considering a completely different function?